# Angular - ng-hide with localStorage doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-hide

I have in my HTML :

```
<div ng-hide="token">
  Test
</div>
```

And in my controller :

```
$scope.token = localStorage.key;
```

But it always return false (?) - it doesn't work.

And if I try to do it like this :

```
<div ng-hide="token()">
  Test
</div>
```

And in Controller :

```
$scope.token = function(){
    return localStorage.key;
}
```

it;s also doesn't work.

why ?

And how do i do it work ?

thanks

Comment: Try injecting `$window` to your controller and then get the token using `$scope.token = $window.localStorage.key;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using localStorage right. The right method is:

```
$scope.token = localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Similarly, you would `setItem` to put something in, and `removeItem` to delete it later.

Complete documentation on localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: I'm able to get the value of a key when I do `localStorage.key = 111;alert(localStorage.key);`

Comment: @AlonEitan you right. but for some reason it's work only if i do it with `getItem()` . I made an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/morwin10/r0ue8qwp/

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is a key/value array.

You can use:

```
    window.localStorage.getItem('key');
    window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
    window.localStorage.removeItem('key');
    window.localStorage.length;
    window.localStorage.key(n);
```

Try to use this if you need to see in the console which value you need:

```
    for (var key in localStorage){
      console.log(key)
    }
```

If you try to assign a default value for your token and it's still don't work it could be a scope problem.

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/hgjrmoru/145/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is like this:

```
$scope.token = function(){
  return localStorage.getItem('key');
}
```

Here's a Demo for all other options :

https://jsfiddle.net/morwin10/r0ue8qwp/